# "'[AnyObject]' is not convertible to '[Dog]?'" error when fetching data from CoreData

Tags: swift, core-data, swift2

I'm having issues when fetching data from Core Data. I'm sorry if my terminology is not specific or precise, but I'm a newbie with Core Data.

I'm on Xcode 7 beta and Swift 2. Device OS is set at 8.4.

The line:

```
let result = try managedContext.executeFetchRequest(dogFetch) as [Dog]?
```

Is giving me this error: *"'[AnyObject]' is not convertible to '[Dog]?'"*.

Full code is here:

```
do {
    let dogEntity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Dog", inManagedObjectContext: managedContext)
    let dog = Dog(entity: dogEntity!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: managedContext)

    let dogName = "Fido"
    let dogFetch = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Dog")

    dogFetch.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "name == %@", dog)

    let result = try managedContext.executeFetchRequest(dogFetch) as [Dog]?

    if let dogs = result {
        if dogs.count == 0 {

            currentDog = Dog(entity: dogEntity!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: managedContext)
            currentDog.name = dogName

        } else {
            currentDog = dogs[0]
        }
    }
} catch let fetchError as NSError {
    print("Could not fetch \(fetchError)")
}
```

}

I've attached an image to show what my Core Data model looks like:

[image]

Core Data classes are "standard", automatically created from Editor > Create NSManagedObjectSubclass:

Dog+CoreDataProperties.swift:

```
import Foundation
import CoreData

extension Dog {

    @NSManaged var name: String?
    @NSManaged var walks: NSOrderedSet?

}
```

Dog.swift:

```
import Foundation
import CoreData

@objc(Dog)
class Dog: NSManagedObject {

// Insert code here to add functionality to your managed object subclass

}
```

and basically the same for Walk+CoreDataProperties.swift and Walk.swift.

--

Edit: the selected answer solves the question. My idea is that either this is a change in Swift 2.x vs Swift 1.x, or the tutorial from which I got the code was wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should do
`managedContext.executeFetchRequest(dogFetch) as? [Dog]`

It's because casting here is not guarateed so you should protect yourself against crash (by casting with `as?`. Above statement means that the `executeFetchRequest` return value should be casted to `[Dog]` (an array which holds `Dog` instances, and it can be empty by the way), but only when possible - otherwise casting will fail and you can handle it properly in catch statement.

Comment: You should provide some explanation of *why* this fixes the error

Comment: Hey @Jojodmo, are you asking me or him?

Comment: @DiegoPetrucci You. Code only answers are helpful to the OP, but aren't very helpful to future visitors

Comment: @Jojodmo I honestly don't know. My idea is that either this is a change in Swift 2.x vs Swift 1.x, or the tutorial from which I got the code was wrong.

Comment: @DiegoPetrucci Don't answer to me - edit the question and add how or why it works so future visitors can find help